# Scala collection hierarchy

Tags: scala, collections

I was looking at a photo that shows the Collections Hierarchy in Scala.

It looks like in the top of the hierarchy there is the Traversable Trait, one step down there is the Iterable Trait which has the iterator() function and going down the road there's List and Array...

Creating a simple List object and trying to invoke iterator() on it threw an error that said it is not a part of List.

Now, I know I can get an Iterable representation of the list and then iterate over it with the Iterator, but my question is more about understanding how this thing works: shouldn't the List class get the iterator() function since Iterator is higher up the same hierarchy?

I'm looking at things in my question in the eyes of a Java developer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List[A]`, as you stated, is an `Iterable[A]` and as such it has an `iterator` method (without brackets) that can be called to obtain an iterator over the elements of the list:

```
val it: Iterator[Int] = List(1, 2, 3).iterator
```

If you call it with brackets `iterator()`, it doesn't work because the iterator method is defined without them in the `GenIterableLike` trait:

```
trait GenIterableLike[+A, +Repr] extends Any with GenTraversableLike[A, Repr] {
  def iterator: Iterator[A]
...
```

You can read about method invocation in scala [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html). *Arity-0* methods can be defined with or without brackets, but if you go for the latter (`def m = {}`), you cannot call them like this: `m()`

Comment: Thanks. I actually feel silly, I did use iterator with no brackets, but I created the list as a Tuple5 (no 'List' before '(1,2,3,4,5)') and that's why I got the 'no iterator' error...

Comment: It happens to the very best, trust me. And I'm not one of them :D